# How to avoid getting adware from SourceForge, or remove SourceForge-installed adware?

Tags: adware, sourceforge

First some background:
A couple of years ago [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net) started adding adware into executables stored on their site.

Because of how they covertly added the adware without asking for permission (and other reasons), their way of handling the process led to the "[DevShare adware controversy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SourceForge#DevShare_adware)" and eventually a conflict with the makers behind [Gimp](http://libregraphicsworld.org/blog/entry/anatomy-of-sourceforge-gimp-controversy), [Nmap](http://seclists.org/nmap-dev/2015/q2/194), [VLC](https://blog.l0cal.com/2015/06/02/what-happened-to-sourceforge/), and [other projects](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2015/06/sourceforge-locked-in-projects-of-fleeing-users-cashed-in-on-malvertising/).

Now considering SourceForge behavior in this matter I do not consider them sufficiently trustworthy and prefer to download either stand-alone zip archives or plain source files (which I compile myself).

Unfortunately neither stand-alone zip nor source code is actually available for all projects.

So for this reason I wanted to ask if there is a standard way to block or delete any SourceForge installed adware? For example, is the adware tied to specific dll(s) that they bundle in the executable?

Comment: Per the California Anti-spyware act, any adware installed on your system must enumerate itself in the add/remove programs applet (appwiz.cpl) and be uninstallable. You will almost certianly find that you can remove it from there. SourceForge may be acting like jerks (fricken Dice; they ruined Slashdot as well) but they are not actual cybercriminals (though it would be nice is web advertising was criminal, or at least implemented strong consumer protections).

Comment: I've been away from Windows for awhile, but I used to use a program called [WinPatrol](https://www.winpatrol.com/winpatrol/).  It alerts you to any attempt to change the system and lets you reject it.